# Flutter JSON list not returning properly

Tags: android, ios, json, dart, flutter

I've been following [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfdG8e9mgU4) to help me return data from an online JSON file into a list view. I've altered the code slightly, including a change in URL to the JSON file and due to this, the code now requests different data.

Something tells me it's because the JSON type I want to use isn't compatible with the code I've used, but I don't know why and might be wrong. I use the original '**StarWarsData', 'StarWarsState'** that the author of the provided video used just to minimise the differences in my code.

Thanks, Jake

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: StarWarsData(),
  ));
}

class StarWarsData extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  StarWarsState createState() => StarWarsState();
}

class StarWarsState extends State<StarWarsData> {
  final String url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/";
  List data;

  Future<String> getSWData() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    setState(() {
      var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
      data = resBody["data"];
    });

    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Star Wars Starships"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Card(
                    child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("Id: "),
                            Text(data[index]["id"],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black87)),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                  Card(
                    child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("Name: "),
                            Text(data[index]["name"],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.red)),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                  Card(
                    child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("Symbol: "),
                            Text(data[index]["symbol"],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black87)),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getSWData();
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

The question has now been fixed, but in case anyone was interested, here is the error I was previously encountering:

```
I/flutter (31850): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY 
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════I/flutter 
(31850): type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' where I/flutter 
(31850): int is from dart:core I/flutter 
(31850): String is from dart:core
```

Comment: Please add the error messages yougot

Comment: The question has already been answered, but just in case you were still interested, here is the error. **I/flutter (31850): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════I/flutter (31850): type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' where
I/flutter (31850):   int is from dart:core
I/flutter (31850):   String is from dart:core**

Comment: If that's not enough just follow me up, I was limited for space in my response

Comment: You can edit the question and add additional information. This way you alsi can properly format it.

Comment: So do you want me to re format the question or give you more of my error? I suppose I should edit my question and add a full log

Comment: I meant adding the content from your previous comment to the question instead to format it properly to make it readable. Even when your problem us solved ut wozld make it more valueable for others with a similar issue.

Comment: Okay, I’ll get to that in a minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue lies here,

```
Text(data[index]["id"],
```

where `"id"` field is an integer and you are using it directly in place of a String.

Change it to,

```
Text('${data[index]["id"]}',
```

Comment: You too, your help is very much appreciated :)